# Compiling Module on Nao robot using custom makefile

Tags: c++, makefile, glibc, nao-robot

I am programming a module for my Alderbaran Nao V5 robot.  Alderbaran recommends using qibuild to compile a module, and I was able to successfully do so, but now I am trying to migrate towards writing my own makefile and using g++.

I am encountering the following error:

```
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.5.3/../../../../lib/crt1.o: In function 

`_start':
(.text+0x18): undefined reference to `main'
/home/nao/naoqi-sdk-2.1.3.3-linux32/lib/libqimessaging.so: undefined reference to `std::__detail::_List_node_base::swap(std::__detail::_List_node_base&, std::__detail::_List_node_base&)@GLIBCXX_3.4.15'
/home/nao/naoqi-sdk-2.1.3.3-linux32/lib/libqi.so: undefined reference to `std::invalid_argument::~invalid_argument()@GLIBCXX_3.4.15'
/home/nao/naoqi-sdk-2.1.3.3-linux32/lib/libqitype.so: undefined reference to `std::out_of_range::~out_of_range()@GLIBCXX_3.4.15'
/home/nao/naoqi-sdk-2.1.3.3-linux32/lib/libqitype.so: undefined reference to `std::__detail::_List_node_base::_M_transfer(std::__detail::_List_node_base*, std::__detail::_List_node_base*)@GLIBCXX_3.4.15'
/home/nao/naoqi-sdk-2.1.3.3-linux32/lib/libqimessaging.so: undefined reference to `std::__detail::_List_node_base::_M_unhook()@GLIBCXX_3.4.15'
/home/nao/naoqi-sdk-2.1.3.3-linux32/lib/libqimessaging.so: undefined reference to `std::__detail::_List_node_base::_M_hook(std::__detail::_List_node_base*)@GLIBCXX_3.4.15'
/home/nao/naoqi-sdk-2.1.3.3-linux32/lib/libqi.so: undefined reference to `posix_spawnp@GLIBC_2.15'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [shm.so] Error 1
```

Here is the makefile I am using:

```
#Variables
CXXFLAGS=-Wall -g
CXX = g++
NaoQi_INC = /home/nao/naoqi-sdk-2.1.3.3-linux32/include
NaoQi_LIB = -L/home/nao/naoqi-sdk-2.1.3.3-linux32/lib -lalcommon -lalerror -lalproxies -lalvalue -lqimessaging -lqitype -lqi

#Object Targets
main.o: main.cpp shm.h
        $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -c -I$(NaoQi_INC)  main.cpp

shm.o: shm.cpp shm.h $(NaoQi_INC)/alcommon/alproxy.h $(NaoQi_INC)/alcommon/albroker.h $(NaoQi_INC)/alcommon/almodule.h
        $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -c -I$(NaoQi_INC) shm.cpp

#Library Targets
shm.so: main.o shm.o
        $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -o shm.so main.o shm.o -L/usr/local/lib -lm  $(NaoQi_LIB)

clean:
        rm -f *o main
        rm -f *o shm

all: shm.o main.o shm.so
```

I noticed that the gentoo operating system I am compiling on has up to GLIBCXX_3.4.14 but does not have GLIBCXX_3.4.15.  How can I fix this issue?  Why would this issue not present itself when I build the module using qibuild?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interestingly, the problem was that my .so linking command was missing a -shared flag.  Not sure why that gave all of the errors I ran into, however.